# Windows Server - Export private key of an already deleted certificate with certutil.exe

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate, certificate-authority

I want to replace my current CA. So I queried the different KSP's and found a private key, which is not used in any certificates issued or stored at this CA. I concluded that this key must be from an already deleted certificate.

Now for backup reasons I wanted to export only the private key but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: what is the point in exporting key without having a certificate?

Comment: Yeah. If some nice day someone comes around with the certificate that used this private key. Who knows. I wasn't the administrator at the time the key was created. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: No. Even if someone comes, what you will do with the key? If CA is decommissioned, delete the key.

Comment: Ok. So I was a bit irritated. If I generate a private-public key pair in Linux, I always have the possibility to export (read) the private key. So i was wondering if that is also possible with Windows... But thx for your comments!

Comment: In certain cases, it is possible (not always). Windows doesn't provide such functionality in a easy way because it is often useless and makes no sense. Based on your question it is the senseless case. Either way, raw key export will require CryptoAPI programming.